# How to make this asp .net code work?

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
//--- menuFac ---
public void UpdatePageById()
{
    db.ModifyData("UPDATE tblsider SET colOverskrift=@1, colTekst=@2  WHERE colID=@3", _overskrift, _tekst, _id);
}

//--- where i'm trying to get some from db to edit and save the edited ---
menuFac objTekst = new menuFac();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        objTekst._id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["colID"]);

        DataRow value = objTekst.GetPageById();

        txtOverskrift.Text = value["colOverskrift"].ToString();
        txtTekst.Text = value["colTekst"].ToString();
    }

}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    objTekst._id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["colID"]);

    objTekst._overskrift = txtOverskrift.Text;
    objTekst._tekst = txtTekst.Text;

    objTekst.UpdatePageById();

    Response.Redirect("Protected.aspx");
}
```

Comment: And what's happening at the moment? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this call method

```
objTekst.UpdatePageById();
```

with

```
this.UpdatePageById();
```

UpdatePageById is method of your `Page Class`, not of your property objTekst

Comment: +1 He can replace all `objTekst` with `this` and remove this line: `menuFac objTekst = new menuFac();` (i assume `menuFac` is the type of his page class)